# How to set UIImage to UIImageView after retrieving from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios4, uiimageview

I am trying to display the image on `uiImageView` using `imagePickerview`.
Meaning the user selects the image ok.
Then I have one button which says save .
So next I have to do is save the image in `NSUserDefaults` 
Then I need this image on another viewController to display the same image on `uiImage` view

For this i did following.

```
       on save  button touched......

     NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image);
    NSData* myEncodedImageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imageData];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myEncodedImageData forKey:@"myEncodedImageDataKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

then retreiving on another viewcontroller .......as

```
           NSData* myEncodedImageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myEncodedImageDataKey"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:myEncodedImageData];
imageView.image =image;
```

But image is not displayed here in the imageView on another view.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an extra and unnecessary step by taking your PNG image data that's in the NSData object and archiving that before storing it to defaults.  NSUserDefaults can handle an NSData object directly.  Trying taking out the archiving/unarchiving, and just work with the NSData object and see if that fixes your issue.